# Fastest way to backup a single file?

Tags: files, backup

I want to quickly create a backup of a file, by creating a duplicate with a '~' at the end, in terminal. Is there any straight forward single command way of doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a shell function

```
backup() {
   cp ${1} ${1}~
}
```

Put it in your shell rc file, for bash it is ~/.bashrc. Source .bashrc or start a new shell.

```
 . ~/.bashrc
 backup youFile
```

And you have a copy of yourFile.

Comment: Thanks, that works great.
But out of curiosity, what exactly is the . ~/.bashrc line doing?

Comment: Henry: That sources your `.bashrc` file in your home directory; it's short form for `source ~/.bashrc`. Doing this will allow you to use the `backup()` function added to the file.

Comment: Clarification: The `. ~/.bashrc` is needed only the once, because it is executed automatically every time you open a terminal.

Comment: whats the difference between this and just copying a file?

Comment: Nothing really, you only need to type in 1 argument instead of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Rsync works Great for backup. It is mostly used for server backup.

```
rsync -avP <source> <destination>
```

Here You can defines source and destination. source may be file or directly on local or Remote server/machine.